# How to set resizable div to not overlap with divs of set size?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a webpage that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiGaI.jpg) picture.

There's a 120px wide sidebar with 100% height and a 75px tall footer with 100% width. I'd like the main div (the white part) to resize depending on the window size and fill up the space not occupied by the sidebar and footer, but not overlap with them at the same time. 
I've tried setting the main div's height and width with percentage points, but it still overlaps with the other divs. Any suggestions?

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/9u9kL1d8/) a link to the code. I've changed the colour of the 'main' div to black, though it's not displayed right now since its dimensions aren't specified.

Here's the CSS part:

```
#main
{
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    bottom: 75px;
}

#footer
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#sidebar
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ff7a0f;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, considering the sidebar is at left and you main div have the id "main":

```
  #main { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 120px;
  bottom: 75px;
  }
```